# Do the minifigure utensil cups stack like 1x1 bricks?

Tags: design

Do Minifigure Utensil Cups stack on top of eachother?
[bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3899&C=5#T=S&C=5&O=%7B%22color%22:%225%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The diameter on top of the cup is larger than stud, but also smaller than the outer diameter of anti-stud.